# How to hide or show button below div according to data more or less

Tags: javascript, html, css

If I run the code without the 'if' condition, the toggle button works very well, but I want the toggle button to hide if I have less data and/or appear if there is more data. I also want a minimum content div height of 100px. Please help me. Thanks.

[image][image][image]

```js
var elmnt = document.querySelector(".backwhite");
var txt = elmnt.clientHeight + "px";
if (txt >= 100 + "px") {
  var mydivh = document.querySelector(".backwhite");
  mydivh.style.height = "100px";

  function toggleDescriptionHeight(e) {
    document.querySelector(".backwhite").classList.toggle('expanded');
    e.target.textContent == 'Expand' ? e.target.textContent = 'Collapse' : e.target.textContent = 'Expand';
  }
  var button = document.querySelector('.btn');
  button.addEventListener('click', toggleDescriptionHeight)
} else {

  var myElements = document.querySelector(".bbttnn");
  myElements.style.display = "none";
  var myElement = document.querySelector(".backwhite");
  myElement.style.height = "100px";
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #f1f3f6;
}
.backwhite {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.backwhite.expanded {
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h4>Description</h4>
  <div class="backwhite">
    <p>1. Create Ui For Email Campaign.</p>
    <p>2. Create Functionality of Email Campaign</p>
    <p>3. Create Keyword Display using Drag And Drop Functionality.</p>
    <p>1. Create Ui For Email Campaign.</p>
    <p>2. Create Functionality of Email Campaign</p>
    <p>3. Create Keyword Display using Drag And Drop Functionality.</p>
    <p>1. Create Ui For Email Campaign.</p>
    <p>2. Create Functionality of Email Campaign</p>
    <p>3. Create Keyword Display using Drag And Drop Functionality.</p>-->
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block">Expand</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were several redefinitions of the same variables, the CSS has been modified to handle all height definitions, and the if statement tidied to remove the 'px' (which interferes with the maths of the comparator).

Note that if the minimum height (which is also best defined in the CSS) is set to 100px then the JS code won't be able to hide the button. So there is an addition count of child divs to allow the button to hide if less than 3.

The code has been generally rearranged and annotated in the snippet below.

```js
var elmnt = document.querySelector(".backwhite"),
  txt = elmnt.clientHeight,
  button = document.querySelector('.btn');
// elmnt only needs to be defined once

function toggleDescriptionHeight(e) {
    elmnt.classList.toggle('expanded');
    if (e.target.textContent === 'Expand') {
      e.target.textContent = 'Collapse';
    } else {
      e.target.textContent = 'Expand';
    }
  } // this function has been moved out of the if condition

if (txt >= 100 && elmnt.children.length > 3) { // the 'txt >= 100 &&' can go
  button.addEventListener('click', toggleDescriptionHeight);
} else {
  button.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #f1f3f6;
}
.backwhite {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
  height: 100px;
  /* height defined here */
  /*  min-height: 100px; */
  overflow: hidden;
}
/* note that if the minimum height is 100 you will always have the button */

.expanded {
  /* this should come after .backwhite */
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h4>Description</h4>
  <div class="backwhite">
    <p>1. Create Ui For Email Campaign.</p>
    <p>2. Create Functionality of Email Campaign</p>
    <p>3. Create Keyword Display using Drag And Drop Functionality.</p>
    <p>1. Create Ui For Email Campaign.</p>
    <p>2. Create Functionality of Email Campaign</p>
    <p>3. Create Keyword Display using Drag And Drop Functionality.</p>
    <p>1. Create Ui For Email Campaign.</p>
    <p>2. Create Functionality of Email Campaign</p>
    <p>3. Create Keyword Display using Drag And Drop Functionality.</p>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block">Expand</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello Sam0, your code is very useful and working very well according to my need.Thanks @Sam0 for help me !!

Comment: Hello Sam,can you help me some more ? Last time you solve my problem but some problem is remaining.You did last time div content was hide or show according to <p> tag. (txt >= 100 && elmnt.children.length > 3) but now i want some images in this div.If i "remove elmnt.children.length > 3" then code work properly but if i put only a line e.g. <p> one or two line which height is less than 100 then toggle button not hide .Please help me .Thanks.

Comment: would it be okay to try your `.backwhite` css `height` as `auto` or even 90 instead of 100? this is the part currently constraining your js condition txt height check